# How would I load a new scene when a score that is stored in a string is reached?

Tags: javascript, gui, unity

This is a code that I am working on for a space shooter. Part of it works and my score does increase by 7 every second while being loaded into a GUI box, but my script does not load my scene when the number reaches 1000. I have made sure that my scene is a part of my build settings and I have tried some fixes but it doesn't load even though I don't get any sort of error. Any Ideas?

```
#pragma strict
function Start(){
InvokeRepeating("EachSecond",1.0,1.0);
}

var score: int = 0;
var addscore = 7;

function EachSecond()
{
score=score+addscore;
}

function OnGUI(){
GUI.Box(Rect(1000,10,100,25), score.ToString());
}
function WinningScore()
{
     if (score >= 1000 )
     {
          Application.LoadLevel("Win");
     }
  }
```

Comment: winingScore function is not been called anywhere :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to call the WinningScore function in the update or in the EachSecond method after you increase your score.